# Kali kill mac EFI

Tags: boot, kali-linux, grub, uefi

I have an old Macbook late 2008. And I decided to use it only with Kali. With one system. During and after the installation of Kali, there were incomprehensible problems with the keyboard, it just did not respond. But Kali I still set. At the beginning of use, it was revealed that the keyboard works for about 5 minutes, then it starts to work wonders, buttons cause pop-ups and open other programs, it becomes impossible to print and it just stops responding to clicks. Kali put the latest release. It was decided to install an earlier release of kali linux. I made a bootable USB and when I tried to turn on the Macbook inEFI mode (holding options key) nothing happened. I tried downloading EFI 40 times, but GRUB started instead. I tried in GRUB to change the boot disk via boot=hd1 (my flash) and chainloader +1 but GRUB throws an EFI error. When Kali starts up, only in 1 out of 8 cases does the keyboard work for entering a password, in other cases it just does not respond (But it works in GRUB)

Comment: so,  what is your question?

Comment: it possible to setup EFI on mac. Or boot USB from GRUB. Most methods used for GRUB isnt work.